# A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Random' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' instead

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

This the error what I get when I try to use one of my code in Unity3D.
Following is the code that I have used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Random;
public class BackgroundTile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] dots;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        int dotToUse = Random.Range(0, dots.Length);
        GameObject dot = Instantiate(dots[dotToUse], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        dot.transform.parent = this.transform;
        dot.name = this.GameObject.name;
    }
}
```

Can you guys tell me where I'm wrong, so that I can correct my code.

Comment: The error message is already quite explicit, not sure what could be added. Just remove the `using UnityEngine.Random;` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UnityEngine.Random` is a static class, not a namespace.

To use `Random.Range`, you simply need to add the using directive for `Random`'s namespace, which is `UnityEngine`.

What you could do is add a static using directive:

```
using static UnityEngine.Random;
```

And by doing this, you could omit the type name from any calls to `Random`'s staic members, for example:

```
int dotToUse = Range(0, dots.Length);
```

Comment: Thankyou, this solved my problem, the other one I'm getting is that I'm getting a warning saying:
Inconsistent files, some are of MacOS and some are of windows.

Comment: @Deatus I'm not sure what would cause that; I would log it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias. To do that you just need to replace

```
using UnityEngine.Random;
```

with

```
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
```

All of the following calls to any Random methods like

```
float x = Random.Range(0f,1f);
```

should now work.